# Builder Pattern involving complex objects

Tags: java, design-patterns

For fundamental types the builder pattern seems to be pretty straight forward. I wanted to understand how it works when you want to build an object having complex member types.

Here I have a Person class and a static inner class to build Person. I have an Address Class that I have defined in the PersonBuilder static nested class. Ideally the Address Class should have been defined in the Person class itself. The code works but I am not sure If I am doing things correctly here. Can anyone please advise if there is a better way to construct these kind of objects.

```
class Person{

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Integer age;
private Person.PersonBuilder.Address address;

private Person(PersonBuilder builder){
    this.firstName =  builder.firstName;
    this.lastName = builder.lastName;
    this.age = builder.age; 
    this.address = builder.address;
}

@Override
 public String toString(){
    return "Person: " + 
           this.firstName + "|" + 
           this.lastName + "|" + 
           this.age.toString() + "|" + 
           this.address.aptNum + "|" +
           this.address.street + "|" +
           this.address.city + "|" +
           this.address.state + "|" +
           this.address.zipCode;
}

public static class PersonBuilder{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Integer age;
    private Address address;

    private class Address{

        private String aptNum;
        private String street;
        private String city;
        private String state;
        private Long zipCode;

        public Address(String aptNum, String street, String city, String state, Long zipCode) {
            this.aptNum = aptNum;
            this.street = street;
            this.city = city;
            this.state = state;
            this.zipCode = zipCode;
        }
    }       

    public PersonBuilder(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = this.new Address("", "", "", "", 0L);
    }

    public PersonBuilder age(Integer age){
        this.age = age;
        return this;            
    }

    public PersonBuilder buildAddress(String aptNum, String street, String city, String state, Long zipCode){
        this.address = new Address(aptNum, street, city, state, zipCode);
        return this;
    }

    public Person build(){
        return new Person(this);
    }
}
```

}

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Person p1 = new Person.PersonBuilder("XYZ", "XYZ")
                              .age(24)
                              .buildAddress("AB", "XYZ Lane", "ABCtown", 
                              "XY", 1234L)
                              .build();

                 System.out.println(p1.toString());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A class should have a single main purpose, but it seems that you are giving two different tasks to `PersonBuilder`: building Persons and constructing Addresses (which is done on the fly while building Person instances).

As suggested before, it would be better if you could make `Address` an independent class and add an `AddressBuilder` there.

This will make it easier for you to modify `Person` and `Address` classes independently.

The address field setter in `PersonBuilder` will also look cleaner, as it could simply receive an already built `Address` instance:

```java
public PersonBuilder address(Address address){
    this.address = address;
    return this;
}
```

Usage would be similar to the example mentioned in a previous answer:

```
Address address = new Adress.AdressBuilder()
                            .aptNum("xyz")
                            .street("xyz")
                            .city("xyz")
                            .state("xyz")
                            .zipCode("xyz")
                            .build();

Person person = new Person.PersonBuilder("ABCD", "EFG")
                          .address(address)
                          .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to define `Address` as public class separately, so it will not be tightly coupled with `Person` and you can reuse it.

You can also create a builder for `Address`. Even if all fields are required, it will make address initialization easier to read.

It will look like this:

```
Address a1 = new Address.AddressBuilder()
                    .aptNum("AB")
                    .street("XYZ Lane")
                    .city("ABCtown")
                    .state("XY")
                    .zipCode("1234L")
                    .build();
Person p1 = new Person.PersonBuilder("XYZ", "XYZ")
                      .age(24)
                      .address(a1)
                      .build();
```